# Java Linked List Problems

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I have two practice problems that I'm having trouble understanding. For # 1, the answer is that the list is printed in reverse, can anyone explain this to me? Also #7, why does the list begin to go backwards once it reaches the null? If anyone can provide some quick explanations it would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

## 1) What does the following function do for a given Linked List if we call it with the head node?

```
void method1(Node<T> node) {
  if(node == null)
    return;

  method1(node.getNext());
  System.out.println(node.getData().toString());
}
```

> a. Prints the nodes of the linked list.
>
> b. Prints the nodes of the linked list in reverse order.
>
> c. Prints alternate nodes of the linked list.
>
> d. Prints alternate nodes in reverse order.
>
> **Answer**
>
> b. Prints the nodes of the linked list in reverse order.

## 7) What is this method going to print, if we call it with the headnode of the linked list 1 → 2 → 3 → 4 → 5 → 6 ?

```
void method1(Node<Integer> node) {
  if (node == null)
    return;
  System.out.printf(“%d ”, node.getData());

  if (node.getNext() != null)
    method1(node.getNext().getNext());
  System.out.printf(“%d ”, node.getData());
}
```

> a. 1 6 2 5 3 4
>
> b. 1 3 5 6 4 2
>
> c. 1 3 5 1 3 5
>
> d. 1 3 5 5 3 1
>
> **Answer**
>
> c. 1 3 5 5 3 1

Comment: Best way to understand questions like these is to write the code and step through it with a debugger. The 1st question is recursive, and the `System.out.println(...)` gets called before the method returns. Try to think the sequence of steps the program will take for a given input list.

Answer (score 1):

Question 1:

This is a recursive method call, meaning it continually calls itself until the break condition is met (in this case, there is no next node to move to). So, let's walk through this line by line.

```
void method1(Node<T> node) {
    if(node == null) // ends the recursive calls without doing anything extra
        return;

    method1(node.getNext()); // Do something with the next node before this node
    System.out.println(node.getData().toString()); // Print contents of current node.
}
```

As you can see, the first time we actually print anything is once we're at the end of the linked list (when `node.next()` returns null). After that first print, the calls move up the stack (and therefore backwards through the list), printing each node's contents as they go.

Question 2:

This is pretty much the same as question 1, just with some twists thrown in. First of all, we're printing the contents of the current node before **and** after the recursive call. So in effect, we'd be printing each node's contents in order, and then in reverse order. The slightly confusing part is that we're calling `method1` on each node, but on every other node, meaning that we're skipping a node each time it's called.

So to summarize the answer to this question, we're effectively printing the contents of the current node, skipping one, printing the contents of the next one, etc... until we reach the end of the available nodes, then we just backtrace and print everything again (only this time in reverse order).

Answer (score 1):

These are both easier to visualize if you draw out the call stack. These instructions are being executed sequentially, so I find it helpful to visualize the sequence of calls and call stack depth like this:

*Question 1:*

```
List = 1 → 2 → 3 → 4 → 5 → 6
method1(1)
  method1(2)
    method1(3)
      method1(4)
        method1(5)
          method1(6)
            method(null)
              return
            println(6)
          println(5)
        println(4)
      println(3)
    println(2)
  println(1)
```

The order of calls here can be seen from top to bottom. `method1` is called before anything is printed. Once `method1` hits the *base case*, it returns to the previous invocation, which in this case is the `method1(6)` invocation.

Each indentation here is another [recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) call, and helps visualize the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack). There are many very good answers explaining recursion better than I could (like this one on [programmers.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25052/in-plain-english-what-is-recursion)).

*Question 7:*

You can do the same thing with this question:

```
1 → 2 → 3 → 4 → 5 → 6
method1(1)
  printf("%f ", 1)
  method1(3) // node.getNext().getNext() = 1 → 2 → 3
    printf("%f ", 3)
    method1(5)
      printf("%f ", 5)
      method1(null) // node.getNext().getNext() = 5 → 6
        return
      printf("%f ", 5)
    printf("%f ", 3)
  printf("%f ", 1)
```